# kubernetes point domain to a local service

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to Kubernetes and trying to point all requests to the domain to another local service.

Both applications are running in the same cluster under a different namespace

Example domains
`a.domain.com` hosting first app
`b.domain.com` hosting the second app

When I do a `curl` request from the first app to the second app (`b.domain.com`). it travels through the internet to the second app.

Usually what I could do is in `/etc/hosts` point `b.domain.com` to localhost.

What do we do in this case in Kubernetes?

I was looking into Network Policies but I'm not sure if it correct approach.

Also As I understood we could just call `service name.namespace:port` from the first app. But I would like to keep the full URL.

Let me know if you need more details to help me solve this.

Comment: was the answer useful?

Comment: Hi @GabrielRobledoAhumada yes it was, just I think Istio is too much for such a simple thing no? at least I think is simple. But apparently anyway I will need to use Istio, becuase I use DigitalOcean, and I want to forward all egress traffic from k8s via VPC to a droplet (So I can get a static IP)

But Kubernetes Gateway API seems promising, but it seems for ingress, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is by using the [Kubernetes Gateway API](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io). Now, it is true that you can deploy your own implementation since this is an Open Source project, but there are a lot of solutions already using it and it would be much easier to learn how to implement those instead.

For what you want, [Istio](https://istio.io) would fit your needs. If your cluster is hosted in a Cloud environment, you can take a look at [Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/anthos), which is the managed version of Istio.

Finally, take a look at the blog [Welcome to the service mesh era](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/welcome-to-the-service-mesh-era-introducing-a-new-istio-blog-post-series), since the traffic management between services is one of the elements of the service mesh paradigm, among others like monitoring, logging, etc.